# Noun phrase with gerund phrase? Noun phrase with participial phrase?

Tags: gerunds, participles

Does the gerund phrase belong to the noun phrase?
Does the participial phrase belong to the noun phrase?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for noted the question, and I have replied to all your answers, all of the are straighforward and clear!

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, commenting to the users who answered a question is not something that is required; I could leave a comment if I don't understand something said in an answer, but _thank you_ comments are not required. Furthermore, comments like "Thank you." or "+1" are generally considered not constructive. The Stack Exchange's way of saying _thank you_ is accepting an answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Accepting an answer is not required too. If you think the user doesn't know how Stack Exchange works, you can tell the user answers can be accepted, possibly not when you think the accepted answer would be yours. (Even better, I would suggest not to add such a comment for questions you answered.)

Comment: I have deleted all my previous comments. I wish to enjoy my stay here, and not waste time in petty fighting.

Answer (score 2):

Even if a gerund is a form derived from a verb that function as a noun, a gerund phrase is considered different from a noun phrase:

- When the phrase start with a gerund that works as noun, the phrase is a *gerund phrase*
- When the head word of the phrase is a noun or an indefinite pronoun, the phrase is a *noun phrase*

A participial phrase is a verb phrase based on a participle and having the function of a participle.

> The horse **trotting up to the fence** hopes that you have an apple or carrot.

> **Eaten by mosquitoes**, we wished that we had made hotel, not campsite, reservations.

Comment: In traditional grammar, gerunds are 'nominals' and 'gerund phrase' is a sub-category of 'noun phrase'. And in orthodox phrase-structure grammars 'noun phrase' (written **N′** and pronounced 'en-bar') is not the same thing as 'Noun Phrase' (written **NP** and pronounced 'en-pee').